# Java SWT: Accelerator shortcut not working on PopUp context menus

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, keyboard-shortcuts, acceleratorkey

I'm adding a PopUp menu to one of my widgets, a Table. It is not working! I only achieved to make work accelerator shortcuts if they are on top menu bar items, and not in popup context menu items. Why?

This is my code, but the table is inside a Composite which is inside another composite:

```
membersTable.setMenu(createMembersPopUpMenu(this));

private Menu createMembersPopUpMenu(Composite parent) {
    Menu popUpMenu = new Menu(parent);

    //Copy
    copyMemberItem = new MenuItem(popUpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
    copyMemberItem.setText("Copiar Miembro");
    copyMemberItem.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 + 'C');
    copyMemberItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            copyMember();
        }
    });

    //Paste
    pasteMemberItem = new MenuItem(popUpMenu, SWT.PUSH);
    pasteMemberItem.setText("Pegar Miembro");
    pasteMemberItem.setAccelerator(SWT.MOD1 + 'V');
    pasteMemberItem.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            pasteMember();
        }
    });

    return popUpMenu;
}
```

Comment: This works fine on macOS. What platform are you using?

Comment: @greg-449 windows 10